# flutter app not connecting to firestore and showing error in build.gradle ,it crashes with ASCII exception

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter

I have been trying to connect firebase to my flutter app but when i did it gradle build failed and errors showing ASCII error apperead.

app level buil.gradle was not able to resolve Properties class an gradleException class[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziUee.png)

my build.gradle file but it was not able to resolve Properties and gradleException.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
   if (flutterRoot == null) {
   throw new GradleException`("Flutter SDK not found. Define location 
 with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
 }

def flutterVersionCode = 
   localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
   flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = 
  localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
  flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.chat"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'